# Apache Spark - Error persisting Dataframe to MemSQL database using JDBC driver

Tags: scala, apache-spark, singlestore

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to save an Apache Spark `DataFrame` loaded from an **Apache Spark temp `table`** **to** a distributed **MemSQL `database`**.
The trick is that **I cannot use `MemSQLContext` connector** for the moment. So I'm using **`JDBC driver`**.

---

Here is my **code**:

```
//store suppliers data from temp table into a dataframe
val suppliers = sqlContext.read.table("tmp_SUPPLIER")
//append data to the target table 
suppliers.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(url_memsql, "R_SUPPLIER", prop_memsql)
```

---

Here is the **error message** (occuring during the `suppliers.write` statement):

```
java.sql.SQLException: Distributed tables must either have a PRIMARY or SHARD key.
```

> **Note**:
>   *R_SUPPLIER* `table` has exactly the same `fields` and `datatypes` than the temp `table` and has a `primary key` set.

---

FYI, here are **some clues**:

1. *R_SUPPLIER* `script`:

   ```
   `CREATE TABLE R_SUPPLIER 
   (
         SUP_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
         SUP_CAGE_CODE CHAR(5) NULL,
         SUP_INTERNAL_SAP_CODE CHAR(5) NULL,
         SUP_NAME VARCHAR(255) NULL,
         SHARD KEY(SUP_ID)
   );`
   ```
2. The **`suppliers.write` statement has worked once**, but data was then loaded in the `DataFrame` **with a `sqlContext.read.jdbc`** command and not `sqlContext.sql` (data was stored in a distant `database` and not in Apache Spark local temp `table`).

---

Did anyone face the same issue, please?

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting that error when you run the create table, or when you run the suppliers.write code? That is an error that you should only get when creating a table. Therefore if you are hitting it when running suppliers.write, your code is probably trying to create and write to a new table, not the one you created before.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer me. It is happening **when the `suppliers.write` statement is called**. I have already used this code and it worked, but the `DataFrame` was loaded with a `sqlContext.read.jdbc` (data was stored on a distant `database` instead of an Apache Spark temp `table`)...

Comment: Can you find out what query run against memsql is producing that error? You could try using query logging by setting `general_log=on` http://docs.memsql.com/docs/trace-log#section-logging-queries. I suspect the JDBC connector is doing something different than expected.